# X ticks different from coordinates in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, coordinates

I have the following problem creating an histogram with pgfplots. I am quite a beginner, so there could be some clear mistakes. When I compile this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xtick={-0.0003, -0.0002, -0.0001, 0, 0.0001, 0.0002, 0.0003},
xmin=-0.0003, xmax=0.0003,
ymin=0, ymax=90,
xticklabels={-3e-4, -2e-4, -1e-4, 0, 1e-4, 2e-4, 3e-4},
ytick={0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80},
ylabel=Number of Occurrences,
enlargelimits=0.05,
ybar interval=0.7,
]
\addplot coordinates {(-0.00027,3) (-0.000231,2) (-0.000192,19) (-0.000153,29) (-0.000114, 49) (-0.000075, 73) (-0.000036,77) (0.000003,87) (0.000042,77) (0.000081,47) (0.000120, 15) (0.000159, 13) (0.000198,6) (0.000237, 2) (0.000276, 1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I get this:

[image]

Therefore, I don't get why:

1) The ticks on the x-axis are not where they are supposed to be and all crowded at a random (?) point of the axis;

2) The x10^-4 is that far from the plot.

As I said I am probably getting something wrong even though it is a simple plot.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You need to say `ybar interval=0.7,` before you set the xtick labels because otherwise this will get overridden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there is a slight misunderstanding of what `ybar interval` does. To see that, look first at the MWE in which I moved the directive up,

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar interval=0.7,
xtick={-0.0003, -0.0002, -0.0001, 0, 0.0001, 0.0002, 0.0003},
xmin=-0.00031, xmax=0.00031,
ymin=0, ymax=90,
%xticklabels={-3e-4, -2e-4, -1e-4, 0, 1e-4, 2e-4, 3e-4},
ytick={0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80},
ylabel=Number of Occurrences,
enlargelimits=0.05,
]
\addplot coordinates {(-0.00027,3) (-0.000231,2) (-0.000192,19) (-0.000153,29) (-0.000114, 49) (-0.000075, 73) (-0.000036,77) (0.000003,87) (0.000042,77) (0.000081,47) (0.000120, 15) (0.000159, 13) (0.000198,6) (0.000237, 2) (0.000276, 1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

According to the text of your question, this may not be quite what you want. However, I'd like to remind you that the pgfplots manual says on p. 87 that

[image]

This means that you may either want to use slightly different coordinates or just to an `ybar` plot. Since my [crystal ball](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOr3L.png) got stolen, I am not sure what precisely you are after, and stop here. However, if you specify this in an update of your question, I'll be happy to try to give it a shot.

Comment: Indeed, I was missing the last coordinate. And yes, I had to put the ybar interval before the xtick. So, the example you provided is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks