# Creating pgfplots graphic with two separate, but synchronized, ordinate axis

Tags: pgfplots

In the following MWE and graph,

Currently, the following graph consists of logarithmically scaled X and Y axis, with units of:

- log(years) on the abscissa (X) axis, and
- log($) on the (traditional) ordinate (Y) axis, respectively.

However, while the:

- LEFT (Y) (traditional) ordinate axis is base-10 ***logarithmic***, the
- RIGHT (X) (new, unique) ordinate axis is *meant* to be ***linear***, e.g. **non**-logarithmic.

Both the LEFT and RIGHT ordinate axis are *meant* to be synchronized, e.g. what logarithmic values are displayed on the LEFT ordinate axis need to be equivalent in non-logarithmic terms to the values that are displayed on the RIGHT ordinate axis.

On the current graph below, the LEFT ordinate axis is **exactly** as I would like it to appear, but the RIGHT ordinate axis is ***NOT***. The abscissa axis is ***exactly*** as it needs to be.

The challenge is that the LEFT ordinate axis **IS** logarithmic, but the RIGHT ordinate axis is **NOT**.

So I'd like for the RIGHT ordinate axis to appropriately show 'tick' marks at 1,050($), 1,100($) and 1,150($) that ***roughly*** correspond to the values on the LEFT ordinate axis of 10^3.0**2**, 10^3.0**4** and 10^3.0**6**.

On the graph below, at the level indicated on the LEFT ordinate axis by the label at 10^3.0**2** log($), on the RIGHT ordinate axis I would like to see (*approximately*, not exactly) the **non**-logarithmic 'tick' mark and label of 1,**0**50($).

Similarly, at the level indicated on the LEFT ordinate axis by the label at 10^3.0**6** log($), on the RIGHT ordinate axis I would like to see (*approximately*, not exactly) the **non**-logarithmic 'tick' mark and label of 1,**1**50($).

Here is the current MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  name=left axis,
  xmode=log,
  xlabel={Year (log scale)},
  ylabel={Cumulative Future Asset Value (log \$ scale)},
  ylabel near ticks,
  ylabel shift = -0.35em,
  legend pos=north west,
  ymajorgrids=true,
  grid style=dashed,
  xtick={1,10,100},
  xticklabels={1,10,100},
  ytick={3.00, 3.02, 3.04, 3.06},
  yticklabels={$10^{3.00}$, $10^{3.02}$, $10^{3.04}$, $10^{3.06}$},
  y tick label style={font=\large},
]

% For r=5%
\addplot[color=blue,domain=1:100,samples=100]
  {log10(1000 * (1 + 0.05)^(log10(\x+1)))};
\addlegendentry{$r=5\%$}

% For r=7%
\addplot[color=red,domain=1:100,samples=100]
  {log10(1000 * (1 + 0.07)^(log10(\x+1)))};
\addlegendentry{$r=7\%$}

\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
  at={(left axis.outer north east)},anchor=outer north west,
  yshift=-0.2cm,
  xshift=-0.161cm,
  yticklabel style={font=\large},
  ytick={2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000},
  yticklabels={2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000},
  ylabel near ticks,
  ylabel={Absolute Future Asset Value (\$)},
  xtick=\empty,
  axis y line*=right,
  axis x line=none,
  scale only axis,
  ymode=log,
  yticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=0, use comma]{\tick}},
]
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The graph as it stands now:

[image: Pgfplot with two separate, but synchronized, axis on left and right of graph.]

Currently, the graph consists of logarithmically scaled X and Y axis, with units of log(years) on the abscissa (X) axis, and log($) on the (traditional) LEFT ordinate (Y) axis, respectively.

The unique, non-traditional, **non**-logarithmic RIGHT linear $ ordinate axis is meant to assist the reader who may not understand how to interpret the logarithmic values on the LEFT log($) ordinate axis.

I've scanned through Dr. Christian Feuersänger's vast **pgfplots** package documentation, but did not see any specific examples of any such dual-ordinate graphics.

FWIIW, I spent of the order of 15+ hours online working with AI in an attempt to get what I was looking for. The biggest hurdle I (and the AI) were working around was the fact that this particular AI could not plot the graphics from LaTeX code, and therefor could not envision or 'see' the output of the code it was suggesting. A major drawback.

To date, and this is where it got tricky working with AI, I (or should I say we?) was (were) able to construct the graph as it now stands. Unfortunately, adjusting the label and 'tick' marks on the RIGHT ordinate axis proved elusive.

This might all just amount to an empty exercise that the **pgfplots** package cannot handle, confirming the difficulty the AI had to deal with.

Please feel free to pepper me with whatever questions you might have. The is NOT a traditional concept that I am attempting to present, particularly for (economist-type) readers who may have never seen such a graph.

Many thanks.

**UPDATE:** Using Rmano's code (See below), and a few tweaks, the final code for the dual axis graphical plot is:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{range/.style={%
        xmin = 0.9,
        xmax = 200,
        ymin = 3.0,
        ymax= 3.07,
    }}
    \begin{axis}[
        range,
        name=left axis,
        xmode=log,
        xlabel={Year (log scale)},
        ylabel={Cumulative Future Asset Value (log \textdollar{} scale)},
        legend pos=north west,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        grid style=dashed,
        xtick={1,10,100},
        xticklabels={1,10,100},
        ytick={3.00, 3.02, 3.04, 3.06},
        yticklabels={$10^{3.00}$, $10^{3.02}$, $10^{3.04}$, $10^{3.06}$},
        ylabel near ticks,
        y tick label style={font=\large},
        axis y line* = left,
              ]
        % For r=5%
        \addplot[color=blue,domain=1:100,samples=100]
            {log10(1000 * (1 + 0.05)^(log10(\x+1)))};
        \addlegendentry{$r=5\%$}
        % For r=7%
        \addplot[color=red,domain=1:100,samples=100]
            {log10(1000 * (1 + 0.07)^(log10(\x+1)))};
        \addlegendentry{$r=7\%$}
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[
        range,
        xmode=log,
        yticklabel style={font=\large},
        ylabel near ticks,
        % this is the same value as the other vertical axis, no sense
        % to have a different label...
        ylabel={Absolute Future Asset Value (\textdollar)},
        % we need ticks at the correct position. fpeval have no log10
        % surely can be automated
        ytick={\fpeval{ln(1000)/ln(10)},
            \fpeval{ln(1050)/ln(10)},
            \fpeval{ln(1100)/ln(10)},
            \fpeval{ln(1150)/ln(10)}},
        yticklabels={{1,000},{1,050},{1,100},{1,150}},
        axis y line*=right,
        axis x line=none,
        ]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and the final graph is:

[image: Dual Ordinate axis graph of logarithmic Asset Values plotted against logarithmic years.]

Comment: I am not sure I understand. The data can be plotted with a logarithmic ordinate axis, or not; linear and logarithmic axis are not proportional. But maybe you just want a secondary vertical axis that, *although* is logarithmic, show the natural values as ticks?

Comment: @Rmano - Yes...Good catch! Notwithstanding my text that states that the RIGHT ordinate axis is non-logarithmic, TO BE EXACT, it is the LABELS on the RIGHT axis that need to express the non-logarithmic values corresponding to the 'tick' marks at 10^3.02, 10^3.04 and 10^3.06. Hiding behind my labeling of the RIGHT ordinate axis as non-logarithmic is the fact that you CANNOT have the scale on one side of the graph be logarithmic and the other side non-logarithmic. Each graph can have only ONE Y scale, either non-logarithmic OR non-logarithmic, but NOT both. The LABELS however, can be interchanged

Comment: Too late now. I'll try a shot at it tomorrow if nobody answer it. 

Comment: One \addplot cannot match both a logrithmic and cartesian grid at the same time.  Now you can create non-regular tick marks which show the log values (at least over one decade or so).

Comment: @John Kormylo - I think that may have been the challenge with the strategy that we were using. Perhaps the best way to go would be to NOT use pgfplots for the second RIGHT ordinate axis, but construct a tikz overlay to accomplish what I'd like to see. Are there any examples of, or online links to, code that demonstrate how LateX can implement your suggestion?

Comment: You can specify the tick values using `[yticks={,,,}]`.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/460364/x-ticks-different-from-coordinates-in-pgfplots for example.

Comment: To All ... I've had a minor medical issue pop-up, and my ability to concentrate is a bit limited. For such a challenging question that AI (and I) had difficulty with, ALL the answers, comments and questions presented ALL deserve a proper answer, one that does justice those answers, comments and questions. Thank you for your patience ... As an aside, all that has happened has revealed an erroneous assumption that I had made from the start, one that essentially made the solution virtually impossible for the AI. Now I have to go wipe the egg off my face with my AI ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is my other interpretation of the problem. Notice that for `pgfplots`, the vertical axis on the left is linear, no logarithmic. The "logarithmic" is created manually with the `log10` in the plot function. The function is plotted against a linear axis that ranges from more or less 3.0 to 3.065.

Once the function is plotted, you can't have a linear axis matching the logarithmic one (or the other way around). I suppose you want an auxiliary axis with the explicit value of `$10^{3.02}$` etc...

In this case, when using multiple axes, the best thing, in my opinion, is to fix the x and y ranges (you could use a common style for this). Then I manually calculated the `ytick` positions on the right vertical axis, which is *the same* as the left one.

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{range/.style={%
        xmin = 0.9,
        xmax = 200,
        ymin = 3.0,
        ymax= 3.07,
    }}
    \begin{axis}[
        range,
        name=left axis,
        xmode=log,
        xlabel={Year (log scale)},
        ylabel={Cumulative Future Asset Value (log \textdollar{} scale)},
        legend pos=north west,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        grid style=dashed,
        xtick={1,10,100},
        xticklabels={1,10,100},
        ytick={3.00, 3.02, 3.04, 3.06},
        yticklabels={$10^{3.00}$, $10^{3.02}$, $10^{3.04}$, $10^{3.06}$},
        ylabel near ticks,
        y tick label style={font=\large},
        axis y line* = left,
              ]
        % For r=5%
        \addplot[color=blue,domain=1:100,samples=100]
            {log10(1000 * (1 + 0.05)^(log10(\x+1)))};
        \addlegendentry{$r=5\%$}
        % For r=7%
        \addplot[color=red,domain=1:100,samples=100]
            {log10(1000 * (1 + 0.07)^(log10(\x+1)))};
        \addlegendentry{$r=7\%$}
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[
        range,
        xmode=log,
        yticklabel style={font=\large},
        ylabel near ticks,
        % this is the same value as the other vertical axis, no sense
        % to have a different label...
        %%% ylabel={Absolute Future Asset Value (\textdollar)},
        % we need ticks at the correct position. fpeval have no log10
        % surely can be automated
        ytick={\fpeval{ln(1000)/ln(10)},
            \fpeval{ln(1050)/ln(10)},
            \fpeval{ln(1100)/ln(10)},
            \fpeval{ln(1150)/ln(10)}},
        yticklabels={1000,1050,1100,1150},
        axis y line*=right,
        axis x line=none,
        ]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ Rmano - Your answer is PRECISELY the image I had imagined from the beginning. As I outlined in my comment to Jasper Habicht below, your answer (I believe) correctly plots the 'tick' marks for the 1,050, 1,100, and 1,150 labels corresponding to the flowing logarithmic values:  corresponding logarithmic values: [log(1,050)=]3.021189, [log(1,100)=]3.041393, and [log(1,150)=]3.060698. If I may make one request before I accept your answer, can you confirm that what I am seeing is what you have coded? Thank you. (For the curious, 10^3.00 = 1,000 EXACTLY, so no extra tick mark is required @ 1000).

Comment: @ Rmano - As an aside, would it be possible to add the following title to the RIGHT ordinate axis: "Absolute Future Asset Value ($)". Thanks again for your superb answer!!

Comment: How do I add commas to the labels on the RIGHT ordinate axis to become, 1,000, 1,050, 1,100, and 1,150 without the code becoming confused as to which commas separate each of the four labels, and which commas are endemic to the labels themselves? This is just so excellent!

Comment: Look at the comment in the code... Ticks position is calculated with the `log` operation, so they are exact. The shown label are in `ytickslabel`, so just add the commas (or whatever) there. Finally, the axis label you want is in the code, just commented out, because I do not understand why you want different labels for the same number... But just uncomment that `ylabel`.

Comment: Thank you for all of your code. As you suggested, I've uncommented the code: `ylabel={Absolute Future Asset Value (\textdollar)},` to add the RIGHT ordinate axis title. That title is key. For those financial types who do NOT deal with logarithms on a regular basis, I'm hoping to have them possibly take more than a milli-second, cursory glance at the graph ... before they move on to their next issue. I also changed the `yticklabels` to read as follows: `yticklabels={{1,000},{1,050},{1,100},{1,150}},` as the added {}'s distinguish between a 000 thousands separator and an axis label.

Comment: I've added the final graph with the changes described above to the body of my original post. Thank you again (and to Jasper Habicht) for all your coding. I'm looking to read what my AI says about the updated graphics code.

Comment: Note that `ytick={log10(1000), log10(1050), log10(1100), log10(1150)},` also works, i.e., no need for `fpeval`.

Answer (score 2):

Not fully sure whether this is what you're after, but if you want to draw two ordinates, you need to set the option `scale only axis` to *both* axes in order to match the scaling of both axes (how to use two ordinates is actually described in section 4.9.11 of the current [PGFPlots manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf), but maybe the AI you used hasn't read this part in detail yet ... ):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
%\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  name=left axis,
  scale only axis,
  xmode=log,
  xlabel={Year (log scale)},
  ylabel={Cumulative Future Asset Value (log \$ scale)},
  ylabel near ticks,
  ylabel shift = -0.35em,
  legend pos=north west,
  ymajorgrids=true,
  grid style=dashed,
  xtick={1,10,100},
  xticklabels={1,10,100},
  ytick={3.00, 3.02, 3.04, 3.06},
  yticklabels={$10^{3.00}$, $10^{3.02}$, $10^{3.04}$, $10^{3.06}$},
  y tick label style={font=\large},
  ytick pos=left,
]

% For r=5%
\addplot[color=blue,domain=1:100,samples=100]
  {log10(1000 * (1 + 0.05)^(log10(\x+1)))};
\addlegendentry{$r=5\%$}

% For r=7%
\addplot[color=red,domain=1:100,samples=100]
  {log10(1000 * (1 + 0.07)^(log10(\x+1)))};
\addlegendentry{$r=7\%$}

\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
  yticklabel style={font=\large},
  ytick distance={1/6},
  yticklabels={0, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000},
  ylabel near ticks,
  ylabel={Absolute Future Asset Value (\$)},
  xtick=\empty,
  axis y line*=right,
  axis x line=none,
  scale only axis,
  ymin=0,
  ymax=1,
]
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

<sub>Using this approach, you will get a warning that one of the plots is empty (which is obvious since the second `axis` environment does not contain any plot at all). You can place an invisible plot (such as `\addplot[draw=none] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};`) to get rid of the warning or just ignore it.</sub>

---

Alternatively (and as you already pointed to in your comment), you could draw an overlay, that is, the right axis manually, for example like this:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
%\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  name=left axis,
  xmode=log,
  xlabel={Year (log scale)},
  ylabel={Cumulative Future Asset Value (log \$ scale)},
  ylabel near ticks,
  ylabel shift = -0.35em,
  legend pos=north west,
  ymajorgrids=true,
  grid style=dashed,
  xtick={1,10,100},
  xticklabels={1,10,100},
  ytick={3.00, 3.02, 3.04, 3.06},
  yticklabels={$10^{3.00}$, $10^{3.02}$, $10^{3.04}$, $10^{3.06}$},
  y tick label style={font=\large},
  ytick pos=left,
]

% For r=5%
\addplot[color=blue,domain=1:100,samples=100]
  {log10(1000 * (1 + 0.05)^(log10(\x+1)))};
\addlegendentry{$r=5\%$}

% For r=7%
\addplot[color=red,domain=1:100,samples=100]
  {log10(1000 * (1 + 0.07)^(log10(\x+1)))};
\addlegendentry{$r=7\%$}

\end{axis}

\draw (left axis.north east) -- (left axis.south east)
    node[midway, xshift=30pt, anchor=north, rotate=90] 
        {Absolute Future Asset Value (\$)}
    foreach \y [count=\i] in {2000, 3000, ..., 8000} {
        coordinate[pos={1-1/6*(\i-1)}] (y-\i) 
        (y-\i) node[right, font=\large] {\y} 
    };

\foreach \i in {1, ..., 7} {
    \draw[thin, lightgray] (y-\i) -- ++(-0.15cm,0);
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(Or create the axis inside the `axis` environment using

```
\draw (axis description cs:1,0) -- (axis description cs:1,1)
    node[midway, xshift=30pt, anchor=north, rotate=90] 
        {Absolute Future Asset Value (\$)}
    foreach \y [count=\i] in {2000, 3000, ..., 8000} {
        coordinate[pos={1-1/6*(\i-1)}] (y-\i) 
        (y-\i) node[right, font=\large] {\y} 
    };

\draw[thin, lightgray] 
    foreach \i in {1, ..., 7} {
        (y-\i) -- ([xshift=-0.15cm]y-\i)
    };
```

)

[image]

Comment: So probably I did not understand the question... I thought that the right ordinate should have the values of the left one. I mean, at 10^{3.02} level, it should read 1047, at 10^{3.04}, 1096... but really, I am not sure. Clearly, if the value is the same I do not understand while the y legends are different...

Comment: @Rmano To be honest, I am not sure either. Maybe the right axis should be logarithmic as well ... I'll just wait for the OP to reply to this. I wanted at least to give some starting points as to how to add another axis to the plot.

Comment: @Jasper Habicht - Thank you for your answer. I realize my instructions may have been confusing at best. FWIIW, Rmano's answer is closer to what I was looking for, with the Absolute Future value on the RIGHT ordinate axis values representing the mirror of the 10^3.02, 10^3.04, and 10^3.06 values on the LEFT ordinate axis, e.g. 1047.129, 1096.478, and 1148.154 respectively. To complicate matters worse, on the RIGHT ordinate axis, I am looking for the 'tick' marks (and their labels) to appear at the following equivalent locations on the RIGHT ordinate axis: 1,050, 1,100, & 1,150 respectively.

Comment: @Jasper Habicht - (continued) What I initially had a hard time understanding was that there is only a SINGLE logarithmic axis, but that the 'tick' marks and labels on the RIGHT ordinate axis (1,050, 1,100, and 1,150) were to be placed as a reflection of the following corresponding logarithmic values: [log(1,050)=]3.021189, [log(1,100)=]3.041393, and [log(1,150)=]3.060698. The end result is that the 'tick' marks and labels on the LEFT ordinate axis are APPROXIMATELY but NOT exactly reflected one-for-one at the same elevation with the 'tick' marks and labels on the RIGHT ordinate axis.

Comment: @Jasper Habicht - (continued) The rounded values of 10^3.02, 10^3.04, and 10^3.06, on the LEFT ordinate axis are an APPROXIMATE reflection of the 1,050, 1,100, and 1,150 values on the RIGHT ordinate axis, but NOT exactly at the same elevations on both the LEFT and RIGHT ordinate axises. Thank you again for you answer.

Comment: @RosesBouquet No need to explain in that much detail. My answer was meant as starting point as to how to place the right axis anyways. It might still be helpful to you. Changing the values is probably not too complicated.